# Convert from IndexedSeq[DataFrame] to DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Newbie question ,
I am try to add columns to exist DataFrame , I am working with Spark 1.4.1

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
case class Test(rule: Int)

val test = sc.parallelize((1 to 2).map(i => Test(i-i))).toDF
test.registerTempTable("test")
test.show

+----+
|rule|
+----+
|   0|
|   0|
+----+
```

Then - add columns, one column - OK

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
val t1 = test.withColumn("1",lit(0) )
t1.show

+----+-+
|rule|1|
+----+-+
|   0|0|
|   0|0|
+----+-+
```

Problem appears when I try to add several columns:

```
val t1 = (1 to 5).map( i => test.withColumn(i,lit(i) ))
t1.show()

error: value show is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a *reduce* process, so instead of using *map*, you can use *foldLeft* with *test* data frame as your initial parameter:

```
val t1 = (1 to 5).foldLeft(test){ case(df, i) => df.withColumn(i.toString, lit(i))}

t1.show
+----+---+---+---+---+---+
|rule|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+
|   0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
|   0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks

Comment: What is a role of `df` ? Do we create five times new `df` to add to `test` ?

Comment: `df` refers to the data frame generated in previous stage. I don't think we are creating data frame five times. As it is the same as `test.withColumn().withColumn()...` or `val df1 = test.withColumn(); val df2 = df1.withColumn();...` Not a super expert to give a definite answer though.