# Summary Statistics of a Array Type Column in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
def toDouble(s: String) = {
  if ("?".equals(s)) Double.NaN else s.toDouble
}
  def parse(line: String) = {
  val pieces = line.split(',')
  val id1 = pieces(0).toInt 
  val scores = pieces.slice(2, 11).map(toDouble)
  val matched = pieces(11).toBoolean
  MatchData(id1, scores, matched)
}
case class MatchData
(
    id1: Int, 
    scores: Array[Double], 
    matched: Boolean
    )
val inputrdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("../donation/block_*.csv")

    val noheader = inputrdd.filter(x => !x.contains("id_1"))
    val df= noheader.map(line => parse(line)).toDF()
```

The schema of the Data Frame is as below

```
root    
|-- id1: integer (nullable = true)    
|-- scores: array (nullable = true)    
|-- element: double (containsNull = false)   
|-- matched: boolean (nullable = true)
```

The first three records are as below

```
 [53113,WrappedArray(0.833333333333333, NaN, 1.0, NaN, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0),true] 
 [47614,WrappedArray(1.0, NaN, 1.0, NaN, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),true]  
 [70237,WrappedArray(1.0, NaN, 1.0, NaN, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),true]
```

I want to get the summary statistics  like count , mean, max , min for each element in the Wrapped Array column.

My idea was to create another DataFrame for the WrappedArray Elements alone by filtering out the NaN values and giving a column alias as the index of the Array Element. 
The use a select on the DataFrame of functions like count(), min() max() etc.
But not without any result.

```
val dfnona = (0 until 9).map(i => {
  df.select("scores").as[Seq[Double]].filter(s=> s(i) !=Double.NaN).alias(i.toString())
})

dfnona.select(count("0"),mean("0"), stddev_pop ("0"),max("0"),min("0")).show()
```

Can someone give me some directions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If the `scores` array is fixed length for entire `DataSet` then you can this solution.

```
val df = ... //create dataframe with schema you mentioned 

//Here $"scores"(0) fetches first element in Scores Array
val subjects = df.withColumn("sub1", $"scores"(0))
  .withColumn("sub2", $"scores"(1))
  .withColumn("sub3", $"scores"(2))
  .withColumn("sub4", $"scores"(3))
  .select("sub1", "sub2", "sub3", "sub4")

// Alternate approach
val numberOfSubjects = 4
val subjects = (0 until numberOfSubjects).foldLeft(df)((accDf, index) => {
  accDf.withColumn(s"sub${index}", $"scores" (index))
})


subjects.printSchema()

root
 |-- sub1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sub2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sub3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sub4: double (nullable = true)
```

Now you can apply all statistical functions on `sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4` columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I came up with.

[This post helped.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726736/convert-from-indexedseqdataframe-to-dataframe) and mrsrinivas above too.

```
val dfs = (1 until 10).foldLeft(parsed) {case (df , i ) => (df.withColumn("score"+i.toString(), $"scores"(i)))}
val scores =  dfs.drop("scores")
for (x<- scores.columns.filter(colname=> colname.contains("score")))
              {
              dfs.filter(!isnan(dfs.col(x))).describe(x).show()
              }
```